# Drawing polygons using latitude/longitude values in D3

Tags: d3.js, latitude-longitude

I have a set of polygons where the position of their vertices (corners) are defined as latitude/longitude values.

I want to use D3 to draw these. I don't want anything fancy (like a background containing the world map, etc). The only thing I want to do is to draw the polygons.

I have looked up on Google for a solution, but what I find is things like http://datamaps.github.io or https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths and they all show a background of the world map or the like which is what I don't want to do.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: The examples you refer to show the world or similar because that's in the data. D3 doesn't do this automatically; if your data contains only the polygons you're interested in, only those will be drawn.

Comment: Can you show a very simple example of how to draw a shape using lat/long then? Let's just use a pretty simple example, like a rectangle whose corners are N30 W30, N30 W31, N31 W31 and N31 W30.

Comment: If your data is in geojson format, then you can simply plug that into any of the examples for drawing geo data. If not, then there's no benefit to using the geo functions and you can use a normal D3 scale to translate the coordinates into screen coordinates.

Comment: My data is currently in the following format (each row being one vertice of the polygon):

N040.35.08.544 W075.00.32.053
N040.35.02.117 W075.00.35.032
N040.34.56.387 W075.00.39.875
...

I can easily convert it into decimal format (from the degree-minute-second format). But I don't know how to use D3 scale to then convert it into screen coordinates.

Comment: Use `d3.scale.linear().domain([minCoord, maxCoord]).range([minScreen, maxScreen])`.

Comment: Okay I created http://jsfiddle.net/5a8ec1dh/ but I how do I draw the actual polygon?

Comment: Parse the coordinates into a data structure and then draw: http://jsfiddle.net/5a8ec1dh/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72473/discussion-between-merik-and-lars-kotthoff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case, using the geo functionality of D3 seems like overkill -- all you need to do is use the D3 scales to convert the coordinates to screen coordinates, i.e.

```
var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([minCoord, maxCoord]).range([minScreen, maxScreen]);
```

Demo (based on provided fiddle) [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5a8ec1dh/1/).